# Can i substitute figure directives in ReStructuredText?

Tags: wordpress, python-sphinx, pandoc, substitution, restructuredtext

I have a .rst document which was imported from Wordpress using wp2rst (which uses pandoc).
During the import, all my images were translated into substituted`.. image::` as such :

```
This is some text |myimage| followed by some more text

.. |myimage| image:: https://myiage.png
    :class:alignnone size-full wp-image-1864
    :width: 1075px
    :height: 135px
```

My images originally have captions. So I tried something like this :

```
This is some text |myimage| followed by some more text

.. |myimage| figure:: https://myimage.png
    :class:alignnone size-full wp-image-1864
    :width: 1075px
    :height: 135px

    This is my figure's caption
```

I get the following error when running Sphinx :

> WARNING: Substitution definition "myimage" empty or invalid.

Working with figures in a more traditional fashion works well, but it would require me to refashion the entirety of

```
This is some text 

.. figure:: https://myimage.png
    :class:alignnone size-full wp-image-1864
    :width: 1075px
    :height: 135px

    This is my figure's caption

followed by some more text
```

Is there a way to create substitutes for `.. figure::` the same way as `.. image::`?

Answer (score 0):

The image substitution definitions are a means to provide for inline images. Figures are always block-level elements, so a substitution definition with figures does not make sense generally.

Writing a script to convert the pandoc output to proper figure directives may be simpler than writing a custom parser with "figure" substitutions.